# Display Maven Project version on Netbeans Application window

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I have a Maven based Netbeans Application. By default the application window title is on this format:

```
<Application Name>{0}
```

Where {0} is replaced at runtime with the IDE build date it appears. Is there a way for this to automatically be the project's Maven version instead?

Right now I need to manually change this on each release. It's just prone to errors.

**Update**
Added the following to the POM but it seem snot to have any effect and Netbeans shows red icons because is not finding some files for a Helps set I have in the module.

```
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/nbm-branding/core/core.jar/org/netbeans/core/startup</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

Comment: Filter with `${project.version}`?

Comment: Tried filtering, but it somehow breaks the Netbean project.

Comment: Define "breaks". Post what you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: Added as requested.

Comment: The issue is still unclear, but with what you have, you'll need to add another `<resource>` that does not filter `src/main/resources`  as well. Something like `<resource><directory>/src/main/resources</directory></resource>`, this is because it was overriden with the one you added.

Comment: That didn't help either.

Comment: Yet, "didn't help" is still not properly defined at all...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134127/discussion-between-javydreamercsw-and-tunaki).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### There are two ways to set the version number shown in the Help... About dialog.

```
The easy way is to set the system property netbeans.buildnumber to some value in your application.
The harder way is to put this key/value currentVersion=My Product 1.2.3 into the file named "branding/modules/org-netbeans-core.jar/org/netbeans/core/ui/Bundle.properties" below your suite, then rebuild and run.
In NB 6.5 and later is the file location different: "branding/core/core.jar/org/netbeans/core/startup/Bundle.properties"
```

### How do I set the version number automatically in maven-based applications?

Within your branding-module use Maven placeholders in Bundle.properties and within the pom.xml filter the bundle by the maven-resources-plugin.

**Note:** Some of the files below are ignored by default in version control by Netbeans so you might need to add them to preserve the changes.

**src/main/nbm-branding/core/core.jar/org/netbeans/core/startup/Bundle.properties:**

```
currentVersion=My app ${project.version}
LBL_splash_window_title=Starting My app ${project.version}
```

**src/main/nbm-branding/modules/org-netbeans-core-windows.jar/org/netbeans/core/windows/view/ui/Bundle.properties:**

```
CTL_MainWindow_Title=My app ${project.version}
CTL_MainWindow_Title_No_Project=My app ${project.version}
```

**src/main/nbm-branding/modules/org-netbeans-core.jar/org/netbeans/core/ui/Bundle.properties:**

```
LBL_ProductInformation=My app ${project.version}
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/nbm-branding</directory>
            <!-- f.e. allow replacing ${project.version} in all property files below src/main/nbm-branding -->
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <targetPath>${basedir}/target/filtered-nbm-branding</targetPath>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>nbm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <!-- use previously filtered branding sources -->
                <brandingSources>${basedir}/target/filtered-nbm-branding</brandingSources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- ... -->
    </plugins>
</build>
```

As answered by [Netbeans Dream Team](https://netbeans.apache.org/wiki/DevFaqVersionNumber) member.